# Ubuntu 16.04 : Internet Drops Within Few Seconds

Tags: 16.04, wireless, xubuntu

I've tried all solutions online, but still having this issue,

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04,

Here is some outputs :

```
Linux:~$ dmesg | grep ath10k
[   13.272755] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.693234] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   13.864343] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board id is not exist in otp, ignore it
[   15.822968] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[   15.822973] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   16.097267] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[  552.408203] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

and Wireless Script output :

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CM6QfHKGzy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wireless info, we see this:

```
Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'FLAT DX' [AC1]>
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FLAT DX"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000012ee0ab0
                    Extra: Last beacon: 284ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

The channel, 10, is quite unusual to select as it’s an overlapped channel. We suspect, also because of this, that the router is set to auto channel select:

> ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!

Here is an interesting discussion of the pitfalls of auto channel select: https://superuser.com/questions/1311149/why-do-wifi-routers-do-such-a-bad-job-of-channel-selection

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

We have worked on some cases where a space in the name of the SSID was detrimental to connectivity. I suggest that you rename the SSID to FLAT_DX or FLATDX or some such.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Still the same issue,
changed the SSID to FLATDX , Chanel 6, 20Mhz, AES, BGN
RegDomain to IS (Temporary)

Comment: Are you located in Iceland?? Then why IS?

Comment: Update: Now Everything is working fine. 
Thnx Chili555

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.