# Intel 8260 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, intel

I am having trouble getting the 8260 card to work with Ubuntu 16.04. I have 2 computers running kernel 4.13.0.38. One computer can connect to my wireless network, and the other cannot.

On the malfunctioning computer - the network interface is up according to ifconfig:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:283045 (283.0 KB)  TX bytes:283045 (283.0 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c2:c6:dc:1d:83  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The chipset is an Intel 8260 which appears to have many problems in Ubuntu. According to lshw, firmware v31 is loading:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 3a
   serial: 00:c2:c6:dc:1d:83
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic firmware=31.560484.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:127 memory:dc000000-dc001fff
```

I have restarted the iwlwifi using modprobe:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

I can see wireless networks, but I cannot connect to them. I have duplicated the network settings on the functioning computer, but to no avail. I have also copied the firmware ucode from /lib/firmware, and this also did not work.

Any ideas on how to perform a "diff" between the two computers?

Comment: Do both run 8260s? If not, a diff is probably not productive.

Comment: Yes both have the 8260 chip. Verified via lshw.

Comment: We could ask for dozens of items but the easiest way is to gather all the data for each in one script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Possibly most important is to tweak your settings like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026395/ubuntu-16-04-internet-drops-within-few-seconds/1026426#1026426 If tweaking your settings is not productive, paste the wireless-info for both here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Great, @chili555 kudos to whoever built this script ;)

Router is broadcasting on channel 11. Station has a width of 20 MHz, and no form of security is enabled.

I changed the regulatory domain appropriately, and unfortunately nothing was resolved.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that I needed to bring the cfg80211 module down to modify the reg domain (for future users).

Demon comp:    https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8xWcqCYG2m/
Working comp: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jRNKdJGxz7/

Comment: One difference I notice is the state of _ifupdown_ in NetworkManager.conf. I changed the value of managed to True on the demon comp and restarted network manager, unfortunately this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: "no form of security is enabled." YIKES! Please try WPA2-AES, often known as CCMP and I suspect both will connect/

Comment: I added a WPA2-AES psk on the router and both computers, and the state of the comps has not changed. One connects, and the other does not. By the way it was quite intentional to omit a psk from our router.

Comment: @chili555 I isolated the problem and moved the thread in case you are interested: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027281/regulatory-domain-is-reset-for-intel-8260

Comment: Please see my comment there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by setting the regulatory domain on my computers and *reflashing my router with country specific firmware*. I noticed that I could set my regulatory domain and connect to the router, but once I pinged a device on the network, my regulatory domain would revert to global (00).

I started with [the standard discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026395/ubuntu-16-04-internet-drops-within-few-seconds/1026426#1026426) of setting the reg domain. I had some problems using crda to set the regulatory domain, so I added options to the *cfg80211* module, as [other users have done](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296195/265040). To make these changes permanent, I had to create the file **/etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf** and add the following:

```
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=US
```

Anyone searching for a diff tool to compare network configurations should use [this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180).