# Regulatory domain is reset for Intel 8260

Tags: networking, server, intel-wireless

I moved this problem from a [previous thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027066/intel-8260-and-ubuntu-16-04) because I have isolated the problem. When my computer boots, I can see that the regulatory domain is set to US.

```
sudo iw reg get

country US: DFS-FCC
```

I can successfully connect to my network, and ping other devices on the network. After about 4 minutes, I lose my network connection and my regulatory domain resets to global.

```
sudo iw reg get

country 00: DFS-UNSET
```

I have had trouble setting my regulatory domain using crda. The file */etc/default/crda* is populated appropriately:

```
REGDOMAIN=US
```

However the output of $crda is always:

```
COUNTRY environment variable not set.
```

My workaround was to add a config file for the cfg80211 module, at */etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf*, with the following:

```
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=US
```

The cfg80211 module appears to successfully set the regulatory domain, until some module which is loaded at ~4 minutes overrides the reg domain. How can I track down and change the module which overrides the reg domain?

Comment: `options cfg80211 ieee80211.conf` I think it should be: `options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=US` Is that what you meant?

Comment: My mistake, I should have copypasted instead of typing.

Comment: Power saving, perhaps? Set it to off and see if it helps: `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and restart NM: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Powersave setting had a different effect.  I tested both powersave ON and OFF. In both settings, `iw reg get` = US until about 5 minutes in when it is reset to global. With powersave = ON, I can ping my router until ~5 minutes. With powersave = OFF, I am "connected" to the network but I cannot ping my router at all. I checked the dmesg logs and noticed that this message occurs periodically: `[ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested`. Is this normal?

Comment: Not normal at all and hard to fix. Let's start here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139201/how-can-i-prevent-my-wifi-driver-from-going-catatonic wd_disable is no longer an available parameter. You might also, experimentally try setting the router to turn off 5 gHz and therefore 802.11AC. This is likely to be guesswork and trial and error.